# How to create a Laravel 5 middleware composer package?

Tags: package, laravel-5, composer-php, middleware

I want to create a composer package for my laravel project, because this code I could need in some other projects. I never create a composer package before, so can someone explain the workflow or are there any great tutorials?

The package should include a middleware, some classes and optionally some routes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `composer init` in the top level directory of your package and answer the questions.

Make sure to not specify dependencies as branches, but always as range of possible versions, and also make sure you use stable versions.

The last point would be to add the correct autoloading - use PSR-4 if possible (i.e. you are using namespaces), PSR-0 otherwise.

That's it for the Composer part.

Comment: So I add a new folder in my vendor directory and use `composer init`. How must the package structure looks like. Like my laravel project? Where should I put my middleware and the other classes?

Comment: You shouldn't do work in the vendor folder. Create a new folder somewhere, go into it (it's supposed to be empty) and run "composer init". This will create the composer.json file you'd need. Then commit this directory to version control. This is now a working Composer package. Adding code that works in Laravel is beyond the scope of this answer, but I suppose that you have to follow some conventions to make use of dependency injection.